# Omniauth Google Outh 2 Keeps Redirecting To Google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I have Google Omniauth 2 correctly authorizing, pulling the email, creating the users and logging in.

However, each time I log out and click my "Log In With Google" link - it directs me to the Google Allow Access page and makes me approve it again and then logs me in.

Is this just how google operates? Is there a way to pass a scope to make it not ask each time?

Here is my omniauth initializer

```
    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
        provider :facebook, '####', '####', :scope => 'email,offline_access', :display => 'popup'
        provider :google_oauth2, '####.apps.googleusercontent.com', '#####', { }
    end
```

Here is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    #redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
    redirect_back_or user
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
  end

end
```

Comment: I would be interested in coming at this from just a ruby perspective.